# How can I get coordinates from Google Places for an array of places and then use the results after all are done?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, google-places-api, google-places

I have an array of place names, e.g.:

```
const places = ['King Square, London', 'Empire State Building', 'Great Wall of China'];
```

I need a new array of objects with the location set for each element in the array of place names, e.g.:

```
const places = [
  { name: 'King Square, London', position: { latitude: ..., longitude: ... } },
  ...
];
```

I would think I have to do something like this:

```
const places = [];

['King Square, London', 'Empire State Building', 'Great Wall of China'].forEach(placeName => {
  axios
  .get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?key=GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY&query=${placeName}`)
  .then(response => {
    if (!!response && !!response.results && !!response.results[0]) {
      const searchResult = response.results[0];

      if (!!searchResult) {
        axios
          .get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY&placeid=${searchResult.place_id}`)
          .then(response => {
            const placeResult = response.result;

            if (!!placeResult) {
              places.push({ name: placeName, position: placeResult.geometry.location })
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

What should it look like such that I can populate `places` and use the array after it has been populated? Do I have to use Promises to make sure it's populated before using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Steps to update the existing code:

1. Store the promises in an array using [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach).
2. Have the callback to [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) *return* the promise (i.e. the return value from `axios.get().then()`).
3. The response of the call to [axios.get()](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#axiosgeturl-config-1) will have a *data* property that contains the results, so use `response.data.results` instead of `response.results`
4. Return the promise again
5. Then after the promises array has been setup, Promise.all() can be used:

   ```
   const places = [];
   //1 - store promises in an array
   var promises = ['King Square, London', 'Empire State Building', 'Great Wall of China'].map(placeName => {
     return axios //2 - return promise
     .get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?key=GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY&query=${placeName}`)
     .then(response => {
       //3 - use response.data.results instead of response.results
       if (!!response && !!response.data && !!response.data.results && !!response.data.results[0]) {
         const searchResult = response.data.results[0];

         if (!!searchResult) {
           return axios //4 return nested promise
             .get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY&placeid=${searchResult.place_id}`)
             .then(response => {
               const placeResult = response.data.result;

               if (!!placeResult) {
                 places.push({ name: placeName, position: placeResult.geometry.location });
               }
             })
         }
       }
     });
   });
   //5 - After promises are done, use the places array
   Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
       console.log('places:', places);
   })
   ```

*Output*:

```
places: [ { name: 'King Square, London',
    position: { lat: 51.52757920000001, lng: -0.0980441 } },
  { name: 'Great Wall of China',
    position: { lat: 40.4319077, lng: 116.5703749 } },
  { name: 'Empire State Building',
    position: { lat: 40.7484405, lng: -73.98566439999999 } } ]
```

#### Sample in client-side Javascript

Below is a port to (client-side) JavaScript. Notice how it is very similar but uses the StackOverflow API (since there will be no CORS issues that way).

```js
var ranks = [];
var promises = [94, 95].map(badgeId => {
  return axios.get(`https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/badges/${badgeId}?site=stackoverflow&order=desc&sort=rank&filter=default`)
    .then(response => {
      var responsebadgeId = response.data.items[0].badge_id;
      return axios.get(`https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/badges/${responsebadgeId}/recipients?site=stackoverflow`)
        .then(response => {
          console.log('pushing rank into array from data: ',response.data.items[0].rank);
          ranks.push(response.data.items[0].rank);
        });
    });
});
Promise.all(promises).then(responses => {
  console.log('promises all callback - ranks:',ranks);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.16.2/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand how to do it. Should it just be `var promises = names.map(name => axios.get(URL1 + ?keyword=' + name).then(response => axios.get(URL2 + '?query=' + response.data.results[0].place_id)`? But how can I retrieve `result.geometry.location`?

Comment: You can still do the second query - see the updated code above